# SharePoint Online Document Library Conditional Required Fields

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepointdocumentlibrary

Using an out of the box SharePoint Document Library, I have a Yes/No metadata field for my content type which is a required field.

If the value is Yes, I will like to then show and make mandatory 3 more fields. A choice field, people field and multiline text box.

I can hide and show the fields using conditional formatting, but struggling to think of a way I can ensure the 3 fields that appear are made a required field.

Does anyone know if this can be done?

My final solution is going to be having multiple Content Types in the Document Library, then when the user selects one, the relevant fields show, then that’s where the hide/show and required/unrequited functionality of the field will come in.

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the column to hide and display according to the values of other columns, and make them a required field when the column is display. If you set it as a required item, you cannot set the conditional formula for the column.So this should not be possible with OOTB methods.

Comment: OK thanks, I think I am going to do this in PowerApps then, using a custom from.

Answer (score 0):

You can make few of simple column types like single line of text, number, date and time, etc. mandatory using SharePoint list validation formula.

For example: [Making a Date field required in case the use select In-progress from a choice field using list validation formula](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/305174/making-a-date-field-required-in-case-the-use-select-in-progress-from-a-choice-fi/305175#305175)

However, list validation formula does not support complex column types like Person or group and Multiple lines of rich text columns.

There is no other SharePoint out of the box way to make columns conditionally required.

So, you have to customize the list/library forms using Power Apps.

Check this documentation: [Customize a Microsoft Lists or SharePoint form by using Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form)